# Sending mail to Nop Commerce Customers in a Console application Project

Tags: c#, oop, e-commerce, nopcommerce

I am beginner in the Nop Commerce Project 2.30. I try to send mails to my Nop Commerce

Clients ( in the database ) in a specific intervel ( every 12 Hours ).

I create new method ( for create List of client list )  in the interface

**Nop.Services.Customers.ICustomerService** and implement this function, class is

**Nop.Services.Customers.CustomerService**. But a problem i can't create this method

as **static** method. Please see image

[image]

Because **CustomerService** class is not contains the default

constructor. This is the only one constructor in the CustomerService Class.

Please see below.

```
 public CustomerService(ICacheManager cacheManager,
            IRepository<Customer> customerRepository,
            IRepository<CustomerRole> customerRoleRepository,
            IRepository<CustomerAttribute> customerAttributeRepository,
            IEncryptionService encryptionService, 
            INewsLetterSubscriptionService newsLetterSubscriptionService,
            RewardPointsSettings rewardPointsSettings, 
            CustomerSettings customerSettings,
            IEventPublisher eventPublisher)
        {
            _cacheManager = cacheManager;
            _customerRepository = customerRepository;
            _customerRoleRepository = customerRoleRepository;
            _customerAttributeRepository = customerAttributeRepository;
            _encryptionService = encryptionService;
            _newsLetterSubscriptionService = newsLetterSubscriptionService;
            _rewardPointsSettings = rewardPointsSettings;
            _customerSettings = customerSettings;
            _eventPublisher = eventPublisher;
        }
```

I am clueless how to call this parameterized constructor in a external program. So i try

to make my function is static. Any Idea to create a static method in nop. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a WebClient function for this task. I create a Action in my MVC application for sending 
email. Call this action by webclient from my console application in specific intervel.

Please see this link for more.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/d60415d9-f1e7-4981-b600-be056f2f7bcd

[http://forums.asp.net/t/1858253.aspx/1?Call+a+MVC3+Controller+Action+in+a+Console+Application+](http://forums.asp.net/t/1858253.aspx/1?Call%20a%20MVC3%20Controller%20Action%20in%20a%20Console%20Application%20)